# Correctly type in parsing json

Tags: java, json, parsing

When parsing a json response, one of the keys can come as a string "value" or null.
I'm parsing the response as:

```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
           "status",
           "code",
           "exception"
    })

    public class Response {

    private String status;        
    private long code; 
    private String exception;


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public long getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }


    public String getException() {
        return exception;
    }

    public void setException(String exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }
```

When I get null, I have error. How can I do it correctly?

I try @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL), but it's not work

```
public class JsonParserResponse  throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JsonParseException, IOException {
    Response resp= new Response();
try{
        JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject({"status":null,"code":0,"exception":""} );
       resp.setStatus(outerObject.getString("status")); System.out.printf("name=%s , value=%s\n", "status", outerObject.getString("status"));
             resp.setCode(outerObject.getInt("code")); System.out.printf("name=%s , value=%s\n", "code",outerObject.getInt("code"));
             resp.setException(outerObject.getString("exception")); System.out.printf("name=%s , value=%s\n","exception" ,outerObject.getString("exception"));
}catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have error^

```
JSONObject["status"] not a string.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:639)
    at ru.JsonParserResponse.parseResult(JsonParserResponse.java:161)
    at ru.JsonParserResponse.main(JsonParserResponse.java:74)
```

Comment: Try Using @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) on your Response class

Comment: @Amal I  use it, but not working

Comment: What is the error/exception?

Comment: @NiVeR add to post

Comment: You should show also the code where the problem happens. `JsonParserResponse.java`

Comment: @NiVeR add code in  JsonParserResponse

Comment: And finally show what is `fileinpath`?

Comment: @NiVeR filepath - {"status":null,"code":0,"exception":""}

Comment: You mean `"{"status":null,"code":0,"exception":""}"`?

Comment: @NiVeR yes, I get json response type: { "status": null, "code": 0, "exception": " " }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help

add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown =true)` on Response class, that will ignore null values (com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.)

and no need to use `JsonProperty` when your variable name same as your JsonProperty

Comment: I's not work or I do this uncorrectly. Add in post all code

Comment: can you also share full exception

Comment: according to your exception, i suggest you don't use outerObject.getString("status") instead of it  use

    Object aObj = outerObject.get("a");
    if(aObj instanceof String){
         resp.setStatus(aObj);
    }

Answer (score 1):

This code should work (it seems you have wrong formatting of json):

```
    String json = "{\"status\":null,\"code\":0,\"exception\":\"\"}";

    JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(json); 

    Response resp = new Response();

    resp.setStatus(outerObject.getString("status"));
    resp.setCode(outerObject.getInt("code"));
    resp.setException(outerObject.getString("exception"));
```

Comment: when do this format, have error org.json.JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: @vasilek Small reminder: you should not remove/replace the backslashes. They are needed.

Comment: I don't remove/replace the backslashes. but it's don't parsing (

Answer (score 0):

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
Try this once at your class hope this will help you.

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Response {
    // code.....
}

Comment: No's not work( because I get not empty value, I get NULL value